# How do I perform a MySQL function using My_Model (Codeigniter)?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using [My Model](https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model) with [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) and I would like to perform a MySQL function on a field within the model.

My SQL function is:

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) from events;
```

Essentially, I would like the same result as:

```
   $this->load->model('event_model');
   $this->event_model->get_all();
```

within my controller but with the start field converted to a Unix Timestamp.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not convert them to UNIX timestamps in PHP?

Comment: In my model or my controller?

Comment: Whichever, I'd suggest the model.

Comment: Fair enough.. but I'm still not exactly sure how to get this to work. I would still like to get *all* fields from all records but have this particular field formatted. Although @Winston's answer is useful, it's not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your model

```
public function get_all()
{
    return $this->db->select('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start)', false)
                ->from('events')
                ->get()
                ->result_array();
}
```

And this in your controller

```
$this->load->model('event_model');
$all = $this->event_model->get_all();
print_r($all);
```

Comment: It seems he's using a "model framework" (https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model) that contains a built-in `get_all` method.

Comment: I would add, `get_all()` must be added within the model extended from MY_Model, and yeah @Rocket-Hazmat is right, the method must have a new name